# morea-framework - Can you add interactive quiz questions

Tags: morea-framework

Is it possible to either:

- build an interactive quiz within the morea framework
  or
- insert an interactive quiz built in HP5/java script or similar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are possible, but I think your second alternative (insert an interactive quiz built in HTML5 or Javascript) is the way to go. There are many packages for quiz building out there, so it seems a lot easier to just pick the one best suited to your needs and then display it within an Experience page.

Comment: If reference would have been there..this answer deserve to be accepted answer.